# Why is my use of hypnotoad crashing on Heroku?

Tags: perl, heroku, mojo, hypnotoad

I'm trying to get hypnotoad with a [Mojolicious::Lite](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite) app running on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) with [Perloku](https://github.com/judofyr/perloku). There's something that doesn't happen when [hypnotoad](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Server/Hypnotoad) gets into its run loop that causes it to crash. I figure I'm missing something simple, but the Heroku docs haven't helped and I haven't been able to coax good error messages out of this.

I start with a very simple application so show some environment variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# today
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $content = "Perl: $^X Pid: $$\n\n";
    foreach my $key ( keys %ENV ) {
        next unless $key =~ /Mojo|toad/i;
        $content .= "$key $ENV{$key}\n";
        }

    $c->stash( content => $content );

    $c->render('index');
    };

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'Welcome';
<p>Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!</p>

<pre>
<%= $content %>
</pre>

@@ layouts/default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

When I run this locally, I have no problem. I see from the environment variables that my program is run under hypnotoad:

```
Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!

Perl: /Users/brian/Dropbox/bin/perls/perl5.20.0 Pid: 40006

HYPNOTOAD_PID 39981
MOJO_HELP 
HYPNOTOAD_TEST 
HYPNOTOAD_EXE /Users/brian/bin/perls/hypnotoad5.20.0
MOJO_REUSE 0.0.0.0:8080:6
HYPNOTOAD_REV 3
HYPNOTOAD_APP /Users/brian/Desktop/toady.d/toady
MOJO_MODE production
MOJO_HOME
HYPNOTOAD_STOP 
HYPNOTOAD_FOREGROUND
```

Now, I deploy this with [Mojolicious::Command::deploy::heroku](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious::Command::deploy::heroku):

```
% toady deploy heroku --create
```

This is running at https://frozen-brushlands-4002.herokuapp.com, using the default Perloku file:

```
#!/bin/sh
./toady daemon --listen http://*:$PORT --mode production
```

This isn't running hypnotoad though, despite some references I've seen that says that's what I should get. The application works, though:

```
Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!

Perl: /app/vendor/perl/bin/perl Pid: 3

MOJO_REUSE 0.0.0.0:12270:4
MOJO_HOME 
MOJO_HELP 
MOJO_MODE production
MOJO_EXE ./toady
```

I figured I could just change the Perloku file to start hypnotoad:

```
#!/bin/sh
/app/vendor/perl/bin/perl /app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad toady
```

hypnotoad starts and almost immediately shuts down with no other log messages:

```
% heroku logs --app ...
2015-01-04T09:23:36.516864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2015-01-04T09:23:38.321628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can change the invocation to use the `-t` to test the app to see if :

```
#!/bin/sh
/app/vendor/perl/bin/perl /app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad -t toady
```

That works and I get the "Everything looks good!" message, so hypnotoad is running:

```
2015-01-04T09:36:36.955680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2015-01-04T09:36:38.340717+00:00 app[web.1]: Everything looks good!
2015-01-04T09:36:39.085887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I turn on Mojo debug logging, but I don't see additional output other than my own statements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

$|++;

my $log = app->log;

$log->level( 'debug' );

$log->debug( "INC: @INC" );

get '/' => sub {
    ...;
    };

$log->debug( "Right before start" );
my $app = app->start;
$log->debug( "Right after start" );

$app; # must return application object
```

I tried other things, such as making it load a module I know is not there and I get the expected "Could not find" error in the logs.

Running from the shell in heroku (`heroku run bash`) was not illuminating. The output of `mojo version` is the same as on my local machine:

```
$ perl vendor/perl-deps/bin/mojo version
CORE
  Perl        (v5.16.2, linux)
  Mojolicious (5.71, Tiger Face)

OPTIONAL
  EV 4.0+                 (n/a)
  IO::Socket::Socks 0.64+ (n/a)
  IO::Socket::SSL 1.84+   (n/a)
  Net::DNS::Native 0.15+  (n/a)

You might want to update your Mojolicious to 5.72.
```

I figure there's something really simple that I'm missing, but at the same time, none of this is architected for easy debugging.

---

Oleg gets a little closer, but there are still problems. I had tried the foreground option before and run into the same problems but failed to mention it.

If I start hypnotoad in the foreground, it tries to bind to an address. It can't bind to port 80 (or 443) and crashes, and it can listen to 127.0.0.1: almost, but it looks like it fails to completely listen:

```
2015-01-13T11:47:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-01-13T11:48:32+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-01-13T11:48:32.735095+00:
00 heroku[api]: Deploy dcab778 by ...
2015-01-13T11:48:32.735095+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v31 created by ...
2015-01-13T11:48:32.969489+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-13T11:48:34.909134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2015-01-13T11:48:36.045985+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't create listen socket: Permission denied at /app/vendor/perl-deps/lib/perl5/Mojo/IOLoop.pm line 120.
2015-01-13T11:48:36.920004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 13
2015-01-13T11:48:36.932014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here's with an unprivileged port:

```
2015-01-13T11:39:10+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-01-13T11:39:44+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-01-13T11:39:44.519679+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy bbd1f68 by ...
2015-01-13T11:39:44.519679+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v29 created by ...
2015-01-13T11:39:44.811111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-13T11:39:47.382298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2015-01-13T11:39:48.454706+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Jan 13 11:39:48 2015] [info] Listening at "http://*:8000".
2015-01-13T11:39:48.454733+00:00 app[web.1]: Server available at http://127.0.0.1:8000.
2015-01-13T11:39:48.454803+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Jan 13 11:39:48 2015] [info] Manager 3 started.
2015-01-13T11:39:48.480084+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Jan 13 11:39:48 2015] [info] Creating process id file "/app/hypnotoad.pid".
2015-01-13T11:40:47.703110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-01-13T11:40:47.702867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-01-13T11:40:48.524470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-01-13T11:40:48.534002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: What is the output of "mojo version" command?

Comment: It's whatever I decide to install. I'm using 5.71.

Comment: The interesting part of `mojo version' output is what optional modules are installed

Comment: Do you suspect something particular? Besides Perl 5.16, it's just Mojolicious 5.71. Nothing else. Have you used Heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Oleg answers the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27917380/2766176), but there are some pieces missing in the assumptions.

First, create a new heroku app and remember the name of the app:

```
$ heroku create
 Creating vast-spire-6174... done, stack is cedar-14
 https://vast-spire-6174.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/vast-spire-6174.git
```

Next, add the Perloku build pack:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/judofyr/perloku.git
```

Create the git repo and setup on Heroku:

```
$ mkdir testapp
$ cd testapp
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a vast-spire-6174
```

To make everything work, you need a *Perloku* file to start `hypnotoad` in the foreground. You have to specify `perl` explicity because the shebang line in `hypnotoad` refers to the temp location of `perl` when it was built and where it no longer is. Change *myapp.pl* to whatever you named your application.

```
#!/bin/sh
/app/vendor/perl/bin/perl /app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad -f myapp.pl
```

To get everything installed, you use a standard *Makefile.PL*. Specify Mojolicious as one of the prerequisites:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
  VERSION   => '0.01',
  PREREQ_PM => {'Mojolicious' => '5.72'},
  test      => {TESTS => 't/*.t'}
);
```

Finally, the app itself, which you can create with `mojo` (which calls is *myapp.ppl*)

```
$ mojo generate lite_app
```

Here's the generated source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Documentation browser under "/perldoc"
plugin 'PODRenderer';

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->render('index');
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'Welcome';
Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!

@@ layouts/default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

You have to modify the basic program since hypnotoad needs a bit of configuration (where the default server does not):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Documentation browser under "/perldoc"
plugin 'PODRenderer';

plugin Config => {
    default => {
        hypnotoad => {
            listen => ["http://*:$ENV{PORT}"]
            }
        }
    };

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->render('index');
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'Welcome';
Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!

@@ layouts/default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

Once you have all the files, commit them, and push to the heroku branch.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

When you push, a hook will start up everything.

```
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.14 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Perloku app detected
remote: -----> Vendoring Perl
remote:        Using Perl 5.18.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        --> Working on /tmp/build_a73f24f0619fa2ab299586098c5e8daf
remote:        Configuring /tmp/build_a73f24f0619fa2ab299586098c5e8daf ... OK
remote:        ==> Found dependencies: Mojolicious
remote:        --> Working on Mojolicious
remote:        Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SR/SRI/Mojolicious-5.72.tar.gz ... OK
remote:        Configuring Mojolicious-5.72 ... OK
remote:        ==> Found dependencies: IO::Socket::IP
remote:        --> Working on IO::Socket::IP
remote:        Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PE/PEVANS/IO-Socket-IP-0.36.tar.gz ... OK
remote:        Configuring IO-Socket-IP-0.36 ... OK
remote:        Building IO-Socket-IP-0.36 ... OK
remote:        Successfully installed IO-Socket-IP-0.36
remote:        Building Mojolicious-5.72 ... OK
remote:        Successfully installed Mojolicious-5.72
remote:        <== Installed dependencies for /tmp/build_a73f24f0619fa2ab299586098c5e8daf. Finishing.
remote:        2 distributions installed
remote:        Dependencies installed
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types   -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Perloku -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 14.1MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5
remote:        https://vast-spire-6174.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/vast-spire-6174.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

The URL of your application shows up toward the end of the output.

Why this was working for me before I don't know. I was letting a mojo command deploy for me, so there could be something to investigate there. However, it's a bit easier to commit and push without the intermediary.

Comment: And how about $PORT? Don't you need to specify on which port hypnotoad should listen?

Comment: Ah, yes I'll fix that up

Answer (score 5):

This is really just a wild guess, but maybe the heroku infrastructure doesn't expect the runner to terminate? If so, you could try to start hypnotoad with `--foreground` or `-f`.

Also, you could try to do some logging from inside the application to see if it ever runs it at all.

Comment: You'll notice I did do logging. This is a wild guess that isn't at all helpful. I prefer answers that aren't guesses.

Comment: Ok, in future I'll refrain from answering you unless I'm sure its the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

After some testing I found a way to run hypnotoad on heroku

**1. Perloku content should looks like this**

```
#!/bin/sh
perl /app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad -f mojocrashtest
```

*Description*

First of all we need to explicity call perl. Because

```
heroku run bash
head /app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad
```

shows

```
#!/tmp/perl/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/perl

eval 'exec /tmp/perl/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/perl  -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0; # not running under some shell
```

where `/tmp/perl/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/perl` doesn't exists. So, `/app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad` will not start, but `perl /app/vendor/perl-deps/bin/hypnotoad` will be ok.

Then we need key `-f` for hypnotoad as @moritz guessed. Otherwise heroku will think that your app finished unexpectedly.

**2. You should start hypnotoad on port $ENV{PORT}**

For `Mojolicious::Lite` you just need to write something like this at the top of your app:

```
plugin Config => {default => {hypnotoad => {listen => ["http://*:$ENV{PORT}"]}}};
```

For full app you can do it inside the `startup` handler.

**3. heroku open**

---

And this is a full code of Mojolicious::Lite application

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# today
use Mojolicious::Lite;

plugin Config => {default => {hypnotoad => {listen => ["http://*:$ENV{PORT}"]}}};

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $content = "Perl: $^X Pid: $$\n\n";
    foreach my $key ( keys %ENV ) {
        next unless $key =~ /Mojo|toad/i;
        $content .= "$key $ENV{$key}\n";
        }

    $c->stash( content => $content );

    $c->render('index');
    };

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'Welcome';
<p>Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!</p>

<pre>
<%= $content %>
</pre>

@@ layouts/default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

heroku logs

```
2015-01-13T12:08:04.843204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2015-01-13T12:08:06.019070+00:00 app[web.1]: Server available at http://127.0.0.1:13533.
2015-01-13T12:08:06.018899+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Jan 13 12:08:06 2015] [info] Listening at "http://*:13533".
2015-01-13T12:08:06.019035+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Jan 13 12:08:06 2015] [info] Manager 3 started.
2015-01-13T12:08:06.055437+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Jan 13 12:08:06 2015] [info] Creating process id file "/app/hypnotoad.pid".
2015-01-13T12:08:06.412283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-01-13T12:08:08.040072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=floating-temple-3676.herokuapp.com request_id=e9f9bb4d-f71f-4b4c-a129-70faf044c38b fwd=194" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=34ms status=200 bytes=586
2015-01-13T12:08:08.029819+00:00 app[web.1]: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /app/mojocrashtest line 13, <DATA> line 39.
2015-01-13T12:08:08.029836+00:00 app[web.1]: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /app/mojocrashtest line 13, <DATA> line 39.
2015-01-13T12:08:08.029839+00:00 app[web.1]: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /app/mojocrashtest line 13, <DATA> line 39.
2015-01-13T12:08:08.029842+00:00 app[web.1]: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /app/mojocrashtest line 13, <DATA> line 39.
```

URL for my app: http://floating-temple-3676.herokuapp.com/
BTW, I didn't use `mojo deploy`, just `git`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've updated the post with logs. Did you get yours to work? Can you show _mojocrashtest_?

Comment: Okay, not deploying through mojo works. There's must be something in  Mojolicious::Command::deploy::heroku that's not working correctly. That's the tiny bit that was missing in all of this.